# Added columns in SpatiaLite won't appear in QGIS (attribute table)

Tags: spatialite, qgis-2

I have a SpatiaLite Database with OSM-Data from planet OSM (imported with the OSM import tool from QGIS 2.0)

Everything is fine so far. I can create, export, delete tables and draw them in QGIS... but when I create a new column in my table with:

```
ALTER TABLE planet_22_points 
ADD xlabel integer DEFAULT 0
```

It will appear in the "DB Manager" and in "QspatiaLite" but NOT in QGIS! So I tried to add a column with QGIS using the attribute table. This actually seems to work, but after saving the table, zack! the columns I was creating before using the SQL command just appears! And that massage comes up:

```
Could not commit changes to layer planet_22_points

Errors: SUCCESS: 1 attribute(s) added.
ERROR: the count of fields is incorrect after addition/removal of fields!
```

[image]

QGIS 2.0.1, SQLite version: 3.7.9; SpatiaLite Library: 4.1.0

Comment: Which version of the spatialite tools (command line or QSpatiaLite) are you using? Are you possibly hitting http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9029 ?

Comment: I see that removing and reloading the spatialite layer in QGIS then shows all the columns. Seems to be a refresh problem.

Comment: same issue here it seems - QGIS 2.6.1, SpatiaLite 4.2.0 - mod_spatialite 7 on maverick. reloading doesn't fix.

Comment: actually may be more related to http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8923

Answer (score 2):

though this question has been out there awhile, i wanted to post what seems to have worked for me (which sounded almost identical to the OP question). Following the bug report from http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8923 to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spatialite-users/FOq1DPRDkJw, i tried the following (python implementation):

```
    conn=sqlite3.connect(dbPath)
    conn.enable_load_extension(True)
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT load_extension(\'/usr/local/lib/mod_spatialite.so\');')  
    sql = 'SELECT UpdateLayerStatistics(\'myTableName\');'
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

and the new column magically appeared in the QGIS attribute table.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, I had this same problem and I found another solution.

Execute these two commands into the spatialite_gui terminal (wait a few seconds):

```
UPDATE geometry_columns_statistics set last_verified = 0;
SELECT UpdateLayerStatistics();
```

Restart QGIS (or reload your project), enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

3. possibility:

use the [spatialite-gui](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index), right click on geometry-column and run 'Update Layer Statistics'. This will run the commands described in the other two posts for you.